# What is the reason to use requestMatchers().antMatchers() without a verb in spring security?

Tags: spring-security

There is a common practice in the Spring security oauth implementation to secure the oauth endpoints with the following line:

`.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")`

The entire setup looks like this:

```
http
  .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
  .and()
  .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
  .and()
  .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

Can someone explain me why that specific line is needed, since the next line explicitly says that all the requests have to be authenticated?

Answer (score 10):

The `requestMatchers` line specifies to which requests the security check applies. The `authorizeRequests` line does the actual security check.

If you leave out the `requestMatchers` line, all requests will get checked in the way `authorizeRequests` specifies. If there are no checks for some requests, checking will succeed by default.

With the `requestMatchers` line, requests that don't match will get checked by the other remaining chains.

Answer (score 3):

Spring Security manages several Servlet filter's chains.

In modern Spring security (v3.2.x and above) each chain configured by `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and applied based on `@Order(...)` class annotations until first reported that it supports `HttpServletRequest`, which is configured via `.requestMatchers()` DSL:

> As of version 3.1, {@code FilterChainProxy} is configured using a list of
>     {@link SecurityFilterChain} instances, each of which contains a {@link RequestMatcher}
>    and a list of filters which should be applied to matching requests. Most applications
>    will only contain a single filter chain, and if you are using the namespace, you don't
>    have to set the chains explicitly. If you require finer-grained control, you can make
>    use of the {@code } namespace element. This defines a URI pattern
>    and the list of filters (as comma-separated bean names) which should be applied to
>     requests which match the pattern. An example configuration might look like this:

```
public class FilterChainProxy extends GenericFilterBean {
...
/**
 * Returns the first filter chain matching the supplied URL.
 *
 * @param request the request to match
 * @return an ordered array of Filters defining the filter chain
 */
private List<Filter> getFilters(HttpServletRequest request) {
    for (SecurityFilterChain chain : filterChains) {
        if (chain.matches(request)) {
            return chain.getFilters();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Then selected chain applied to secure request.

Your setting only applied to 3 URLs leaving all other URLs unsecured if otherwise isn't configured.