# Exclude URL from requiresSecure()

Tags: spring-security

I have an application where I want to force HTTPS for all requests except one. For that one URL I don't care if it is HTTP/HTTPS.

I currently have the following security config

```
http.requiresChannel()
        .antMatchers("/actuator/health").requiresInsecure()
        .antMatchers("/*").requiresSecure();
```

The issue is that this **requires** actuators health endpoint to be accessed on HTTPs, but I don't really care what protocol is used (I would prefer both).
When you configure authorization you have permitAll, which doesn't care if you are authenticated or not, why is the not a similar mechanism for channel security.

Does anyone know how to exclude a URL from the channel security mechanism.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42133553/5277820.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a regex-matcher that matches all urls except the one you want to exclude like:

```
http...
 .and()
   .requiresChannel()
   .regexMatchers("^((?!/actuator/health).)*$").requiresSecure();`
```

note I'am not a regex-expert (possibly there is improvement needed)

Comment: That was my best suggestion as well, and it works well with one excluded URL, but the pattern would be ugly if you had many. I’m wondering if there is a technical limitation, that I don’t know since Spring doesn’t have ‘permitAllChannels’ method...???

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try something like this:

```
http.requiresChannel()
  .antMatchers("/actuator/health").requires(ChannelDecisionManagerImpl.ANY_CHANNEL)
    .anyRequest().requiresSecure();
```