# Spring requestMatchers, antMatchers and authorizeRequests usage

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am trying to understand what is the use of requestMatchers, antMatchers and authorizeRequests.

1. What happens if we just use requestMatchers?

   http.requestMatchers();
2. What happens what if use requestMatchers and antMatchers?

   http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/", "/login");
3. What happens what if use requestMatchers, antMatchers and authorizeRequests?

   http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/", "/login").and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

So in case 3 does requestMatchers() makes exception for '/login' and '/' so they won't be authenticated or does it mean they too need authentication.

This whole putting requestMatchers() before authorizeRequests() makes it confusing. Need to know what they exactly do and what combining antmacthers will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What happens if we just use requestMatchers? http.requestMatchers();

It's just a useless method call. In English, it reads as: For all the incoming http requests, i want to filter them based on this list of matchers, and of course there is no list of matches, so it does nothing.

> What happens what if use requestMatchers and antMatchers?
>
> http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/", "/login");

Another useless method call. In English, it reads as: For all the incoming http requests, filter them based on this list of matchers, "/", and the "/login", but you do not tell it what to do, so again it does nothing.

> What happens what if use requestMatchers, antMatchers and
>   authorizeRequests?
>
> http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/",
>   "/login").and().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

That's much better. In English, it reads as: For all the incoming http requests, i want to filter them based on this list of matchers, i.e "/", and the "/login" , and i want them to be accessible only by an authenticated user.

If you are using Spring Security, Spring will then check its `SecurityContext`(stored in a `ThreadLocal` variable) to find out if there is an `Authentication` object that contains the `Principal`(the authenticated user, which is often an instance of the `UserDetails` object). If it has, the request is allowed to continue, if not, you get an ugly 403, forbidden.

> So in case 3 does requestMatchers() makes exception for '/login' and
>   '/' so they won't be authenticated or does it mean they too need
>   authentication.

As per above.

The thing is Spring Boot via Spring Security has made it so easy for us, with just a few lines of configurations to get started with a solid security base. Just try it out, within an hour or so, you will be on your way to production.

Good luck mate!

Comment: If I understand https://stackoverflow.com/a/52942283/14098666 correctly, "What happens what if use [only] requestMatchers and antMatchers?" does not actually seem to be useless.

Answer (score 0):

1. meaningless
   2.add some paths with ant mode which were used to be matched with url in incoming request,if match up,the filterchain with those paths will be chosen to filter that incoming request.
   3.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated() means authenticate all of incoming requests by that selected filterchain.
   In a word,requestMatchers was used to set paths to match with what request you want,authorizeRequests was used to authenticate those requests according to the rule you set by some method like antMatchers("XXX").permitAll().